# Fitbit expires_in oauth2 token is always 30 days

Tags: oauth-2.0, fitbit

I'm using Implicit Grant Flow to authenticate over oauth2 and obtaining token from fitbit platform.
Here is the url I'm requesting:

```
https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=CLIENT_ID&expires_in=31536000&prompt=none&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&scope=activity%20heartrate%20sleep;
```

Since I'm specifying expires_in=31536000 I'm looking for a 1 year validity token, but I'm receiving a response like this:

```
fitbit://mypersonalcallback#access_token=ey...VE&user_id=blablabla&scope=sleep+activity+heartrate&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=2567006
```

So my token lasts 30 days.
How can I obtain a 1 year token?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the documentation (https://dev.fitbit.com/reference/web-api/oauth2/#authorization-page) the expires_in can have the following values: 86400 for 1 day, 604800 for 1 week, 2592000 for 30 days, 31536000 for 1 year

Comment: Hmm, sorry. Don't know.